# Binary Search Tree Insertion C++ rooted at current node

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree, insertion

I need to add an item to a binary tree given only the item to be added.

Here is the code I'm given:

```
void BinaryTree::add(Data * data) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = new BinaryTreeNode(data);
    }
    else {
        root->add(data);
    }
}
```

where `root` is a private variable of a `BinaryTree` defined as a `BinaryTreeNode`.

I need to implement a method:

```
void BinaryTreeNode::add(Data * data);
```

where a `BinaryTreeNode` is:

```
class BinaryTreeNode {
public:
    Data * nodeData;
    BinaryTreeNode * left;
    BinaryTreeNode * right;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    BinaryTreeNode(
        Data * data,
        BinaryTreeNode * left = NULL,
        BinaryTreeNode *right = NULL
    )
      : nodeData(data), left(left), right(right)
    { }

    // ...
```

I want to do this recursively, but I'm not positive how when you're only passed the data to be added.

My idea that doesn't work is:

```
void BinaryTreeNode::add(Data * newData) {
    BinaryTreeNode * temp = this;
    if (temp == NULL) {
        temp->nodeData = newData;
    } else {
        if (newData->compareTo(nodeData) < 0) {
            temp->left->add(newData);
        } else {
            temp->right->add(newData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no good reason to edit the code out of your question.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting temp to this and then comparing it to NULL.  this should never be NULL.  You need to check if the left and right are NULL.

Comment: thanks, that's actually what i just realized and i got it running.

Answer (score 0):

Well a binary tree, atleast how I know how to implement involves something like the following with two objects, one containing the the treenode object, and the other acting as an interface for the whole tree.

```
 class cBinaryTree {

 public:
 bool insert(int inData);
 //Other operations

 private:
 cBinaryTreeNode* root;
 bool leftInsertion;
 cBinaryTreeNode* getRoot() { return root; }
```

As you are comparing the actually value of the input data and placing it accordingly, this qualifies as a binary search tree. Then the insertion function can be written as

```
bool cBinaryTree::insert(int inData) {

//handle case if its first node.
cBinaryTreeNode *Parent = getInsertionNodePosition(getRoot(), inData);
cBinaryTreeNode *newNode = createNewNode(inData);

if(leftInsertion) //insert into left. add return statement
    Parent->setLeftChild() = newNode;
else //insert into right 
}
```

The recursive lookup function will be something like

```
cBinaryTreeNode* getInsertionNodePosition(cBinaryTreeNode* node,int inData) {

//Check left subtree and proceed from there.
if(inData < node->getData()) {
    if(node->getLeftChild() == NULL)  {             
        leftInsertion = true;
        return node;
    }
    else {
        node = node->getLeftChild();
        return getInsertionNodePosition(node, inData);
    }
}
    //Similarly Check right subtree.
```

Hope this helps.